# If $G$ is finite group, $H$ is normal in $G$ if, and only if, $G/H$ is group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $G$ is finite group, $H$ is normal in $G$ if, and only if, $G/H$ is group ?

I know that if $ H $ is normal then the quotient is group, but it's reciprocal?

Comment: To make it more precise, $H$ is normal in $G$ if the map from $G\to G/H$ that sends $g\mapsto gH$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G/H$ be the set of left cosets of $H$ in $G$. For this to be a group we need an operation; the only one which makes sense to use is the operation of the group. Thus we want $xH\cdot yH$ to be a coset itself, say $zH$. Since $H$ is a subgroup $1\in H$ so $xy \in zH$ so we might as well take $z= xy$. This implies 
$$xHyH= xyH$$
Which implies that $HyH = yH$. Since $1\in H$ again, this implies $Hy \subset yH$, and hence $H$ is normal.

Answer (score 0):

The operation in $G/H$ given by $gH \cdot g'H = gg'H$ is well defined iff $H$ is normal.

Comment: Then the operation is well defined, $ H $ is normal? @lhf